# How can I pass a parameter when initializing a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two controllers, `First- and SecondViewController`. I want to share some methods of FirstViewController to use them in my SecondViewController.

This is how I create SecondViewController in FirstViewController:

```
sms = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:sms];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

I thought of passing the current instance of the FirstViewController to the SecondViewController which extends `UIViewController`. By default the initWithNibName method of SecondViewController is called.

How do I achieve this in objective-c?

Comment: are you asking how to pass the FirstViewController into the SecondViewController in the init method without using the initWithNibName initializer?

Comment: I don't call the initWithNibName mehtod, it seems to be called automatically, however I appreciate any suggestion on how to pass the first to the second view controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not completely sure I understand the problem... as part of the issue has to do with how you are instantiating SecondViewController... posting that code could help.

but to answer your question as you have asked it.... "how to pass FirstViewController into SecondViewController"...

in your SecondViewController.h create your own init method

```
-(id) initWithFirstViewController:(UIViewController *)theFirstViewController;
```

and in the .m file...

```
-(id) initWithFirstViewController:(UIViewController *)theFirstViewController
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:@"myNibName" bundle:nil];

 self.firstViewController = theFirstViewController; //this assumes you have created this property.  Also, do NOT retain the first view controller or you will get circular reference and will secondviewcontroller will leak.



return self;

}
```

then.. and here is the key.. make sure you are calling the correct init method to instantiate SecondViewContoller

```
SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithFirstViewController:self];
```

now.. having said that.. looking at your SO rating, I have a feeling you already knew this.. and the real question may be... why is the initWithNibName being called when you are not actually calling it explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are after. The content of your question about sharing methods doesn't seemt o match the question of passing in a parameter at init.

With regard to methods, you can call a method from your parentViewController

```
if ([self.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]) {
    [self.parentViewController someMethod];
}
```

If you want to pass a parameter in on any class at `init`, you will want to write a custom `init` method with any additional parameters you want. That custom method should begin with the appropriate `[self init]` call. You can even have multiple custom `init` methods which can be handy.

Here is an example for class that downloads json or xml feeds.

```
- (id)initWithID:(NSString *)useID delegate:(id)setDelegate urlString:(NSString *)urlString feedIsJSON:(BOOL)feedIsJSON failedRetrySecondsOrNegative:(float)failedRetrySecondsOrNegative refreshSecondsOrNegative:(float)refreshSecondsOrNegative {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // Custom initialization        
        processing = NO;
        self.delegate = setDelegate;

        self.feedID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", useID];
        self.feedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlString];
        self.isJSON = feedIsJSON;

        if (failedRetrySecondsOrNegative>=0.0f) {
            retryFailedSeconds = failedRetrySecondsOrNegative;
        } else {
            retryFailedSeconds = kFailedRefresh;
        }

        if (refreshSecondsOrNegative>=0.0f) {
            refreshSeconds = refreshSecondsOrNegative;
        } else {
            refreshSeconds = kSuccededRefresh;
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope this helps.